# Telerik RadDatePicker set ClientEvents-OnDateSelected from javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, telerik-raddatepicker

I use a combination of different controls in an ASP.Net Repeater. Included are now already 2 RadComboBoxes. I add the SelectedIndexChanged to them in this way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < aClientIds.length; i++) {
     var comboBox = $find(aClientIds[i]);
     var id = comboBox.get_id();
     comboBox.add_selectedIndexChanged(ddlList_SelectedIndexChanged);
}
```

The list of ClientIds are saved to a hidden field from Codebehind and retrieved to a JavaScript array in the js.file associated with the usercontrol where the Repeater is shown. Works nicely. 
I also must include a RadDatePicker and attach ClientEvents-OnDateSelected in the same way. Already have this working and get the correct id:

```
for (var i = 0; i < aDateClientIds.length; i++) {
     var calendar = $find(aDateClientIds[i]);
     var id = calendar.get_id();
     alert('id:' + id);
}
```

But how do I attach ClientEvents-OnDateSelected from JavaScript? I can't find this in the Telerik documentation or on Google

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it with attached event , you should use some hidden field or bool var in javascript for you solution.

As i saw on telerik forum:
[adding-ondateselected-event-method-dynamically-for-raddatepicker](http://www.telerik.com/forums/adding-ondateselected-event-method-dynamically-for-raddatepicker)